# Angular ng-class with class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I've found similar questions here but not this and its a most simple use case: using class and ng-class on the same element.

I have a UL generated with ng-repeat. The LI get styling with an .item class and the selected LI gets an .active class added dynamically with ng-class if it's the currently selected LI (user).

If I only use ng-class, it works. But, when I want to add a standard class, it does not.

Whats up? Much thanks ---

This works and the selected LI gets the .active class.

```
<li ng-repeat="user in mainList.users" ng-class="{'active':isCurrentUser(user)}">
```

This doesn't work:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in mainList.users" class="item" ng-class="{'active':isCurrentUser(user)}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is always a workaround :D :

```
<li  ng-repeat="user in mainList.users" ng-class="{'item' : true, 'active': isCurrentUser(user)}">
   {{user}}
</li>
```

Im not sure your suppose to have those quotations when your calling the classes in ng-class but if one dosent work check the other. Hope this helped!

Comment: `'item' : true` isn't needed there.. I don't understand, why you think that `class="item"` will get removed..?

Comment: That didnt work according to the question asked @PankajParkar . Im just giving a work-around.

Comment: it was my bad, it was working the whole time. I tried to delete the question but could not. This also works so I've accepted it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, I have tested and it works.

```
<li ng-repeat="user in mainList.users" class="item ng-class:{'active':isCurrentUser(user)}">
```

Comment: I don't this would work, could you share working example?

Comment: I have tested this, it works if isCurrentUser(user) returns a true value. Check this https://jsfiddle.net/ashecret/Lt7aP/2400/

Comment: This to me is the better solution. +1.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess you're overwriting the class by using class and ng-class. Could you put item: true in the ng-class as a way of getting around that?

Answer (score 0):

if I remember truely, you can do it like this :

```
<li class="item" ng-repeat="user in mainList.users" ng-class="{'active':isCurrentUser(user)}">
```

the class suppose to be first. It will work if you dont have the same attributes in both classes.

Also if it doesn't work you can try to do it like this:

```
<!-- add the text-error class if wrong is true -->
<div class="item ng-class:{ 'text-error': wrong };">Stuff Goes Here</div>
```

If you still have problems I recommend you to visit this blog : 
[The Many Ways To Use ng-class](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass)

enjoy!